# Проверка слова распространены

Tags: проверочные-слова

Как проверить слово "распространены"?

Answer (score 1):

Рас/про/стран/ен/ы.

Приставка РАС, С перед П (глух.).

Приставка ПРО  постоянного состава, многозначная.

Корень СТРАН, сторона — распространить, черед. ОРО/РА,

ЕН — суффикс краткого причастия, окончание Ы.

Answer (score 1):

Корень можно проверить - пространство

Приставка  рас- без ударения всегда а, под ударением о, согласный с по правилу правописания с перед глухими в приставках на з/с

Приставка про - неизменяемая в этом значении (в другом может и А -прадед)

Answer (score 0):

Корень «-распростран-» глагола «распространять» образован путем сложения приставки «рас-» с корнем «-простран-». Известно, что в приставках «рас-рос-» под ударением пишется буква «о», без ударения – «а». Так можно объяснить правописание буквы «а» в первом слоге глагола «распространять». Правописание некоторых гласных в исходном корне можно проверить. Например, существительное «пространство», в котором буква «а» находится под ударением, помогает правильно написать безударную гласную в третьем слоге слова «распространять». Чтобы проверить гласную «о» во втором слоге данного глагола, следует вспомнить, что существительное «пространство» произошло от праславянского глагола prosteri, что значит «разложить, разостлать».